# Subsetting a list object when inside a for loop in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R. I'm trying to run a for loop on an object containing several lists, but subset the list within the for loop.

Here's an example of my input list, called `mylist`:

```
$Signatures
                       Term Overlap      P.value Adjusted.P.value Old.P.value
1 Cancer of thyroid GSE5364 249/300 1.446206e-57     2.053613e-55           0
2       Dehydration GSE4130 242/300 1.778527e-51     1.262754e-49           0
  Old.Adjusted.P.value Odds.Ratio Combined.Score
1                    0   8.062782      1055.2441
2                    0   6.879966       803.9657
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
$Functions
                           Term   Overlap       P.value Adjusted.P.value
1      RNA binding (GO:0003723) 1042/1387 4.661788e-183    5.104658e-180
2 cadherin binding (GO:0045296)   224/313  4.215416e-33     2.307940e-30
  Old.P.value Old.Adjusted.P.value Odds.Ratio Combined.Score
1           0                    0   5.449901      2288.0519
2           0                    0   4.129599       307.8474
                                         Genes

$Components
                        Term  Overlap      P.value Adjusted.P.value Old.P.value
1 mitochondrion (GO:0005739) 658/1026 1.123362e-65     4.852924e-63           0
2     nucleolus (GO:0005730)  468/676 3.024792e-61     6.533551e-59           0
  Old.Adjusted.P.value Odds.Ratio Combined.Score
1                    0   3.044080       455.2473
2                    0   3.779538       526.6819
```

To run the function by subsetting the list, I would do:

```
plotEn(mylist[[1]], orderBy = "Adjusted.P.value")
```

But how do I subset the list when it's in a for loop? This is clearly the wrong way to go about it:

```
for (k in listobject) {
  setEPS()
  text = paste0(k,".eps")
  postscript(text)
  plotEn(k[[1]], orderBy = "Adjusted.P.value")
  dev.off()
}
```

Where `listobject` is a vector containing about 100 lists in the format of `mylist`. What I'd like to do is loop through each list object in `listobject` and for each one subset the first nested list, i.e. `[[1]]`, to generate the plot. I hope that makes sense.

There are many similar questions on here but I can't adapt their solutions correctly enough to solve my problem. Thanks for your help - it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `for (k in 1:length(mylist))`  and then `mylist[[k]]`

Comment: Or if `k` is a member of `mylist` as  `for (k in mylist)` says it it, then `plotEn(k, orderBy = "Adjusted.P.value")` will do, no need for an index.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions. I couldn't get it work but I realized that was because my question was lacking some detail. I've now updated the original post. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Most likely what you should do is iterate through the names of the list, so that it can be printed and then call the relevant object from the list:

```
for (k in names(listobject)) {
  setEPS()
  text = paste0(k,".eps")
  postscript(text)
  plotEn(listobject[[k]], orderBy = "Adjusted.P.value")
  dev.off()
}
```